# Php htaccess RewriteRule how to fix

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i get the $_GET['id'] from url to show a page, to htaccess i have the follow code to show like this `shop/123` and not `shop.php?id=123`

```
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule shop/(.*)/ shop.php?id=$1
RewriteRule shop/(.*) shop.php?id=$1
```

My problem is .. If i add to url  `shop/123/test/test/test` this still working again and i have problems with the share links etc.

How i can fix it to takes only one parametes else to go to 404?

Sorry for my English

Comment: What is the accepted characters for `id`? Is it only digits?

Comment: for the moment yes. is only numeric

Answer (score 3):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^shop/([^/]+)$ /shop.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This will rewrite /shop/foobar to /shop.php?id=foobar, but will not rewrite /shop/foobar/ with a traling slash or extra path-info .

Answer (score 1):

If `id` is only numerical, you can change the rewrite rule to this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule shop/(\d+)/ shop.php?id=$1
RewriteRule shop/(\d+) shop.php?id=$1
```

If you also have alphabets in `id`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule shop/([a-zA-Z\d]+)/ shop.php?id=$1
RewriteRule shop/([a-zA-Z\d]+) shop.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
    </IfModule>

   RewriteRule ^shop/([0-9]+)/(.*) shop.php?id=$1 [L]
   RewriteRule ^shop/([0-9]+)/(.*)/ shop.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Hope this will work. Thanks.